# How to Have a Knockout Grid Display Header and Data Based on a Dropdown Result

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to make a grid display data that a user selects based on a dropdown menu using knockout. If for example my dataset is:

`{"Data":[{"Avg. Number of Insects":9, "Percent of Damage to Leaves":67.5},{"Avg. Number of Insects":8, "Percent of Damage to Leaves":33.9},{"Avg. Number of Insects":10, "Percent of Damage to Leaves":10.4},{"Avg. Number of Insects":10, "Percent of Damage to Leaves":21.6}]}`

and I have drop down menus for the student to select which variables they want to work with (normally there would be more than two) and want to display the actual data based on which variables they have selected. I tried starting with simpleGrid but it doesn't seem to respond to the header and row changing.

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anyaejohnson/z2cma7ya/7/

Comment: Really should use jsfiddle when posting this... But My guess of what you need to do (didn't read over everything) is to make a computed for your headder and fill it with the data you need via reading the choice of the dropdown... you might have to subscribe to dropdown.. Pretty much do the following but instead of populating a second dropdown, populate your header: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Answer (score 0):

To populate your header simply follow the example here: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html but instead of using the data from category to populate product, use category to populate  an observable array of which you bind to the header

Comment: I've made a JS Fiddle with the relevant code from my current set up [link](http://jsfiddle.net/anyaejohnson/z2cma7ya/7/)

I started trying to switch to how it is setup in the cartEditor, but am confused about how to even get my data to show up in the first place since it is organized by column not row. 

Beyond that, I tried to get the "Product" header to be populated based on category chosen and am confused why what I currently have isn't working: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/anyaejohnson/0bpjwpkq/1/) Do you mean that I need to make a new variable in the ViewModel?